# Calling an external rake task from Rails: dependency issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependencies, rake, bundler

I am currently developing a standalone ruby application alongside a Rails application that works as its frontend. I am managing the dependencies of the Ruby app with Bundler, so there are two gemfiles.

I have a problem trying to execute the Ruby application from the Rails frontend via a system call to a rake task.

When I call the rake task from a standard IRB, it works; but if I try to call the task from a Rails controller or the rails console, dependency issues arise.

As a workaround I can add all the gems not present in the Rails application to the Rails Gemfile, but I guess this approach is wrong.

I think it might be a problem with the scope of Bundler. How could I work around this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fork do
  Dir.chdir("/your/project/dir")
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __FILE__)
  Bundler.setup
  exec "rake -T"
end
```

Comment: Similarly, it is sometimes useful to set `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = ""`.